# Window resize in a method p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I had created a start menu with. This start menu and the little game should react to windows resize changes.

```js
function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

But when I write the start menu in an extra method the start menu doesn't react to the window's size. 
I solved the problem as I wrote all in the `draw()` function. You can see below my solution. But how can I write the 'startMenu' and the 'howToPlayMenu' in a method and that the methods react when I change the window's size. As I said this code below works fine, when I change the windows size. But when I wrote it in a method, it didn't work.

```
function startMenu() {
    hide = false;
}

function howToPlay() {
    hide = true;
}

function draw() {
    if (!started) {
        if (!hide) {
            background(back);
            fill(255);
            textSize(28);
            text('Click me', width / 8, height / 3);
            playButton.show();
            playButton.position(width / 4, height / 2);
            playButton.size(150, 65);
            playButton.style("font-size:50px");
            playButton.mousePressed(start);

            levelSelectorSlider.show();
            levelSelectorSlider.position(2 * width / 3 - 50, height / 2 - 100);
            textSize(28);
            text("Set level", 2 * width / 3 - 20, height / 2 - 120);
            textSize(20)
            text("Easy", 2 * width / 3 - 70, height / 2 - 50);
            text("Medium", 2 * width / 3, height / 2 - 50);
            text("Hard", 2 * width / 3 + 90, height / 2 - 50);

            highScoreButton.show();
            highScoreButton.position(2 * width / 3 - 50, height / 2);
            highScoreButton.size(160, 40);
            highScoreButton.style("font-size:20px");
            highScoreButton.mousePressed(start);

            howToPlayButton.show();
            howToPlayButton.position(2 * width / 3 - 50, height / 2 + 100);
            howToPlayButton.size(160, 40);
            howToPlayButton.style("font-size:20px");
            howToPlayButton.mousePressed(howToPlay);
            goBackButton.hide();
        }
        else {
            background(howToPlayImage);
            playButton.hide();
            highScoreButton.hide();
            howToPlayButton.hide();
            levelSelectorSlider.hide();
            goBackButton.show();
            goBackButton.position(50, 20);
            goBackButton.size(70, 40);
            goBackButton.style("font-size:20px");
            goBackButton.mousePressed(startMenu);
        }
    }
    else {
        //startMenu();
        background(gameBackground); 
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: its not super clear what you are asking, but the window resize event listener might help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Call the startMenu and howToPlayMenu functions inside the windowResized function again. This will redefine the positions of the elements with the new width and height of the canvas